# cpanm fails to install module; gives usage message

Tags: perl, module, cpanm

```
tyler@tyler:~$ cpanm −−local−lib HTML::Parser
Usage: cpanm [options] Module [...]

Try `cpanm --help` or `man cpanm` for more options.
```

Why is it giving me a usage message? I copy-pasted that command straight from Intermediate Perl (page 23). local::lib is installed.

This one, however, does work: `cpanm -L extlib Plack`

**EDIT**

Replacing --local-lib with -l or -L doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The --local-lib option needs to take a parameter, just like you are doing in your second example: `-L extlib`

You probably want `-l ~/p5libs` or something of that nature, depending on where you want your libraries installed. The default directory that local::lib uses is ~/perl5, so it's not a bad idea to use that. :)